# How do I proof that the cluster covariance matrix is symmetric?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, clustering

I was reading Fuzzy clustering with volume prototypes
and adaptive cluster merging by Kaymak, U and Setnes, M.
Here it is written the following equation
\begin{equation}
P_i=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N} u_{ik}^m(x_k-v_i)(x_k-v_i)^T}{\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_{ik}^m}
\end{equation}
where  **i** represent the $i^{th}$ cluster 
and it is said that above matrix is symmetric.
I don't understand how can i proof this.

You can find a copy of the paper [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FucyW3t0GGa5qe5oNIwdpLTr3Yy9ReF0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix $A$ is said to be symmetric if $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^T$, where superscript $T$ stands for matrix transpose.

Forget cluster index $i$ (just assume you take one cluster), the formula becomes
$$
\mathbf{P} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_{k}^m(\mathbf{x}_k-\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{x}_k-\mathbf{v})^T}{\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_{k}^m},
$$
where $\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{v}$ are vectors and $u_{k}^m$ are scalars. Let $\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_{k}^m} = \beta$ and $\mathbf{a}_k = \sqrt{u_k^m}(\mathbf{x}_k-\mathbf{v})$, then
$$
\mathbf{P}=\beta\sum_{k=1}^N \mathbf{a}_k\mathbf{a}_k^T.
$$
Hence, $\mathbf{P}$ is symmetric since (using [properties of matrix transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties))
$$
\mathbf{P}^T = \beta^T\sum_{k=1}^N (\mathbf{a}_k\mathbf{a}_k^T)^T = \beta \sum_{k=1}^N \mathbf{a}_k\mathbf{a}_k^T = \mathbf{P}.
$$

Comment: is that means  determinant of P will always give a positive value ?

Comment: @AnisurRahmanTonu Well, a covariance matrix is (symmetric and) positive definite. We know that all eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix are positive, and we know that the determinant of a matrix is the product of the eigenvalues. We conclude that, the determinant of a covariance matrix is always positive.